# Capture a header in AWS API Gateway integration request to use in Path Override

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

in AWS API Gateway, we want to capture the `X-Amzn-Trace-Id` header in the `integration request` and use it in `path override` so that it can be used as the object name for the new object created. I tried this(attached) based on my previous experience and the docs, but it didn't work:

[image: This is what I tried.]

Anyone know how to do it, or has any ideas? Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you declare this header in the method request?  (It is "Mapped from" `method.request...`)

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what gave the error. Now I don't get that error. But I am not able to use the variable `{ctype}` (the header variable) in **Path override** in a way similar to a path variable declared with `method.request.path.var_name`

Comment: You need to create a header parameter in the method side before mapping to the integration request.